# Python cleaning data frame rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a data frame that looks like a dummy data frame I made below. I extracted this data from an excel sheet, and I need to clean the dataset. More specifically, I want to keep the rows that have numbers on 'Col_1'. In this case, it would be keeping rows from index 0-1, and dropping everything after.

```
                    Col_1 Col_2     Col_3
0                   09374     7  Company1
1                   09374     6  Company2
2                   09374     3  Company3
3                     nan   nan       nan
4                     nan   nan       nan
5                     nan   nan       nan
6                     nan   nan       nan
7           Time 00:19...   nan       nan
```

I know how to drop rows with the specified conditions, and that's not the challenge I am encountering.The challenge is that I need to assume that the types of data in Col_1 or any other columns can switch for other excel files. Thus, the code needs to be flexible when identifying which rows to drop. For example, if I write code that only keeps values in 'Col_1' that can be converted to integers (That is the way I would approach this if the values in 'Col_1' is always supposed to be numbers), then the code would work if the values in 'Col_1' is supposed to be characters in other excel file. For example...

```
                    Col_1 Col_2     Col_3
0                   a0be3     7  Company1
1                   a0be3     6  Company2
2                   a0be3     3  Company3
3                     nan   nan       nan
4                     nan   nan       nan
5                     nan   nan       nan
6                     nan   nan       nan
7           Time 00:19...   nan       nan
```

I also do not want to reference the NaN values either, since there might be excel sheet that does not contain any NaN values.

How can I make the code more flexible so that it always knows which rows to be dropped, regardless of what types of values are in the columns? Also, if there are any ways that I don't have to use loops, that would be amazing.

Comment: `df[~df['Col_1'].isna()]`? This would simply drop all rows for which the `'Col_1'`-value is `nan`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and select for `Col_1` not n/a by [`.notna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html), as follows:

```
df.loc[df['Col_1'].notna()]
```